# Tweets per second calculator (Talent Buddy)

Tags: c#, performance, algorithm, programming-challenge

This challenge is from [Talent Buddy](https://www.talentbuddy.co/challenge/52a9121cc8a6c2dc91481f8d5233cc274af0110af382f40f):

> > Tweets per second
>
> Japan Castle in the Sky airing broke a Twitter record on August 3,
>   2013. At one point during the classic anime movie showing, people submitted 143,199 tweets per second. This particular spike was about
>   25 times greater than Twitter’s steady state.
>
> Given an array of integers representing the number of tweets recorded
>   every second and an integer value K, your task is to write a function
>   that prints to the standard output (stdout) the highest number of
>   tweets recorded between each second in the array and the past K
>   seconds before it
>
> Note that your function will receive the following arguments: tps,
>   which is an array of integers representing the number of tweets
>   recorded every second, and k, which is the integer number mentioned
>   above.
>
> Data constraints: the length of the array above will not exceed
>   500,000 numbers
>
> Efficiency constraints: your function is expected to print the
>   requested result and return in less than 2 seconds
>
> Example Input
>
> tps: 6, 9, 4, 7, 4, 1
>
> k: 3 Output
>
> 6 9 9 9 7 7 Please Note: The above program should run in below 2
>   seconds

**Below is my code in c#**

```
public void tweets_per_second(int[] tps, int k) {
    // Write your code here
    // To print results to the standard output you can use Console.WriteLine()
    // Example: Console.WriteLine("Hello world!");

    for(int i=0; i<tps.Length;i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(FindMaxLastK(tps, i, k));

    }
}
// method to check the maximum of last k items in the array
public int FindMaxLastK(int[] tps, int start, int k)
{
    k = k-1;
    int max = 0;
 while(k >= 0 && start >= 0)
 {
     max = tps[start] > max? tps[start]:max;
     k--;
     start--;
 }
    return max;
}
```

The code has been accepted by the website,  but somehow I feel it can be done better. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

### Naming

Your `FindMaxLastK` method doesn't describe it's intention very well, what is `tps` and `k` when viewed at a glance?. What you have is a windowing function finding the max within that window. Name your function after that:

```
static int MaxInWindow(int[] values, int start, int trailingWindowSize)
```

---

The conditional expression in your max function could be clearer if you used [`Math.Max(int, int)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cs0a3045(v=vs.110).aspx)

---

My implementation would look like:

```
public static int MaxInWindow(int[] values, int start, int trailingWindowSize)
{
    //TODO Validate arguments
    var lowerBound = Math.Max(start - trailingWindowSize, -1);
    var max = values[start];
    for (int index = start - 1; index > lowerBound; index--)
    {
        max = Math.Max(max, values[index]);
    }
    return max;
}
```

### Performance

Your solution is `O(m * n)` where `m` is the number of seconds and `n` is the window size. I just saw the [answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/54674/34163) in a related question and the [optimal solution](http://people.cs.uct.ac.za/~ksmith/articles/sliding_window_minimum.html) is `O(m)`.

The solution uses a [`LinkedList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7(v=vs.110).aspx) to keep track of the max in the window. Here is my implementation in C#:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> MaxInSlidingWindow<T>(T[] values, int windowSize)
{
    var comparer = Comparer<T>.Default;
    var window = new LinkedList<Tuple<T, int>>();// Max at position and position

    var length = values.Length;
    for (var index = 0; index < length; index++)
    {
        var value = values[index];
        while (window.Count != 0 && comparer.Compare(window.Last.Value.Item1, value) < 0)
        {
            window.RemoveLast();
        }

        window.AddLast(Tuple.Create(value, index));

        while (window.First.Value.Item2 <= index - windowSize)
        {
            window.RemoveFirst();
        }

        yield return window.First.Value.Item1;
    }
}
```